# onclick="window.open" + html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a storyline file that is being opened with an onclick event in a new window in my index file. I have the following code.

```
<div class="ease col-6 filterDiv interactives">
    <img class="display-b img-fluid" src="assets/images/digital-wellness-thumbnail.jpg" alt="alt">
        <a onclick="window.open('assets/storyline/digital-wellness/story.html', '_blank', 'location=yes,width=1024,height=768,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')">
            <div class="overlay">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg text-overlay"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

This is opening a storyline file, (before saying "just edit the story.html file", I have tried this, it doesn't work) and I want to see if there is a way to append some html after the story.html file is opened in a new window. Is this possible?

Comment: use localStorage

Comment: Be a more clear as to what you want. In which file do you want to append 'some html'?

Comment: the anchor tag has the file story.html. that is the file that opens in a new window. it is an Articulate Storyline file. Inside of the new window, I was wondering if there was a way to add more html to the window after the story.html file that's being loaded in the anchor tag.

Comment: Append some HTML to what exactly? The content of the new window?

Comment: where exactly do you want to append the html to? - to the`story.html` that gets opened in a new window?, if possible illustrate by providing a screen shot at the minimum if not a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a handle to the new window and modify its HTML by sending it a message with the [postMessage() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). The new window's page will have to know how to accept the message and what to do with it:

Main Page:

```
document.getElementById('my-link').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const newWindow = window.open('http://example.com/new-window.html');

  newWindow.postMessage('<div>Some HTML</div>', 'http://example.com/index.html');
});
```

New Window Page:

```
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin !== 'http://example.com/index.html') return;

  // Do something with event.message, which contains the HTML
}
```

Please read through the entire documentation as it gives good examples for how to get this up and running.

---

Edit for inline:

```
<a onclick="javascript:var newWindow = window.open('assets/storyline/digital-wellness/
story.html','_blank', 'location=yes,width=1024,height=768,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
newWindow.postMessage('<div>Some HTML</div>', '/index.html');">
    <div class="overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg text-overlay"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I can't actually do it through external javascript files is the problem. I have to have the onclick even because javascript is treating the new window as a new tab.

Comment: @Nick0989 I'm not sure I understand the issue. It shouldn't matter if it's a tab or something else - that doesn't affect something being inline or not. Also, it doesn't have to be in an external file, you can have a `<script>` tag with JavaScript code right in your HTML. If you absolutely have to, you actually can include the code inside the tag it is just highly recommended to not do that since it is very hard to manage and couples JavaScript code to your HTML markup.

Comment: It matters to my boss. lol. :) Don't worry about it! I'll try this solution. I thought there was just an easier way to open a window and add additional html within the same line of code. :) thanks though.

Comment: @Nick0989 I see -- well I edited so you can see how you can do this inline as well, but you still need to have a `<script>` on the new window's HTML page for it to accept the message.